# Pre-1970 story - secretary ensures boss' success surreptitiously

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

This is a story I read in the last few years probably by a woman author, but I'm sure it's old. On a trade mission to an alien planet, the male executive in charge is making no progress, but his secretary secretly gives him useful ideas and uses other tricks to ensure that the mission is a success without him knowing.  They may marry at the end.

Comment: I feel compelled to note that this is [absolutely a trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GirlFriday) (if not [two](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HyperCompetentSidekick)), and I'm pretty sure I've read the _Recycled in Space_ version more than once.

Comment: Agreed. Hopefully I'll recognize the specific one I'm looking for

Comment: It was an alien world - I've edited to clarify

Comment: It’s only the greatest Simpson’s episode ever - and Karl was the secretary.

Comment: Now, now. Homer was well aware that he couldn't do anything without Karl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

["Satisfaction Guaranteed"](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/51727/51727-h/51727-h.htm) by Joy Leache, Galaxy, December 1961

**On a trade mission to an alien planet, the male executive in charge**

> Andrew Stephens was trying to think of two things at once, and it
> wasn't working out. An inspirational message (delivered by Crumbly,
> president of Planetary Promotions, Inc.) was mixing itself up in his
> mind with the probable difficulties of his first company assignment.
>
> He hoped he was thinking, and not worrying. Crumbly said worry was
> fatal in the promotion business. It was fervor, not fret, Crumbly
> said, that had made Planetary Promotions, Inc., what it was today. And
> it was work, not worry, that would make it what it was destined to be
> tomorrow.
>
> Andy Stephens stared at the farthest corner of his office (about four
> feet from his nose) and sighed. He didn't have a slogan in his body,
> let alone on (or off) the top of his head.
>
> His assignment was an easy one, Crumbly had assured him. Planetary
> Promotions always started new men off with easy ones. Only fair.
>
> Andy squared his narrowish shoulders in as close an imitation of
> Crumbly's desk-side manner as he could, and picked up the dope sheet.
>
> It seemed there was a planet, Felix II, somewhere near the edge of
> nowhere. It wanted to join the Galactic Federation.
>
> A laudable desire, Andy thought, but strictly a political matter,
> having nothing to do with Planetary Promotions, or Andrew Stephens.
>
> However, it also seemed that a planet had to demonstrate that it would
> be contributing something to the Federation before it was allowed to
> join. In other words, Andy thought, you have to have something they
> want, or they won't let you in.
>
> A buzzer squawked out of the dun-colored box on his desk. Andy jumped,
> and flipped the lever.
>
> "The bus to the port will be at the door in seven minutes," the grim
> voice of the Lower Office Co-ordinator told him. "A stenographer will
> meet you on the ship."
>
> "Thank you, Miss Ellis," Andy said meekly. He stuffed the dope sheet
> into his jacket and left the Main Office for Felix II.

**but his secretary secretly gives him useful ideas and uses other tricks to ensure that the mission is a success without him knowing.**

> Andy was not, as Blahrog had suggested, very drunk. He was only hung
> over. "Get your tooth fixed?" he asked cheerlessly.
>
> "Yes."
>
> "Good dentist?"
>
> Miss Featherpenny nodded. "He had some entirely new equipment.
> Extremely powerful, and quite precise."
>
> "Oh?" Andy straightened in the old arm chair. "I've been trying to
> think. And drinking. Throatduster isn't working this time." He paused
> to reconsider. "Except that it makes me drunk. Everything keeps
> getting fuzzy, and my head is wider than my shoulders."
>
> "The dentist said," Miss Featherpenny persisted, "that he could pull a
> whale's tooth as easily and smoothly as he pulled mine."
>
> "You had to have it pulled? Too bad." Andy made a face at the full mug
> of Throatduster on the barrel beside him. "The Felicians won't change
> their minds about the shoes, and they won't try tourists again. I
> can't think of anything else. And they can claim the guarantee. I was
> bluffing."
>
> "I know," Miss Featherpenny said. She tried again. "The dentist claims
> even the tiniest species could do dental work on the biggest species."
> She paused, hoping it would sink in. "Providing the tiny species had
> sufficient dexterity."
>
> "Blasted Felicians," Andy muttered. "Stubborn little pigs."
>
> "That's part of their trouble, I think," Miss Featherpenny said.
> "Being little, I mean. But it doesn't always work against them. When
> they're doing delicate work...."
>
> "Like those shoes," Andy agreed. "'Best possible shapes already,'" he
> imitated Blahrog.
>
> "They're one of the smallest intelligent species," Miss Featherpenny
> said in desperation. "And their manual dexterity rating is one of the
> highest. Why, a Felician could get both hands inside an Earther's
> mouth."
>
> "And steal his fillings...." Andy started. **"Wait a minute. You've
> given me an idea."**
>
> **Miss Featherpenny breathed relief. "I have? What is it?"**
>
> **"Dentists! They can all be dentists."**

**They may marry at the end.**

> Andy agreed. "But never mind. Let's go home and get married."
>
> "You're a little sudden."
>
> Andy grinned. "I'll have a raise coming for this, and I'd like to keep
> you in the family. I can't seem to think unless you're around."
>
> "Took you long enough to notice," said Miss Featherpenny. But she
> didn't say it out loud.

Comment: I suppose the story is pretty progressive for 1960s science fiction insofar as it shows a woman as more competent than her red-blooded male boss, but a clearly more skilled female employee being given marriage instead of a promotion (or  her boss's job, which it seems she richly deserves) definitely seems like a 60s happy ending. Then again, perhaps that story would have had a hard time being published back then.